# Type hints for lxml?

Tags: python-3.x, types, lxml, mypy, lxml.html

New to Python and come from a statically typed language background. I want type hints for https://lxml.de just for ease of development (mypy flagging issues and suggesting methods would be nice!)

To my knowledge, this is a python 2.0 module and doesn’t have types. Currently I’ve used https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubgen.html to create stub type definitions and filling in “any”-types I’m using with more information, but it’s *really* hacky. Are there any safer ways to get type hints?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is an official stubs package for `lxml` now called [`lxml-stubs`](https://pypi.org/project/lxml-stubs/):

```
$ pip install lxml-stubs
```

Note, however, that the stubs are still in development and are not 100% complete yet (although very much usable from my experience). These stubs were once part of `typeshed`, then curated by Jelle Zijlstra after removal and now are developed as part of the `lxml` project.

If you want the development version of the stubs, install via

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/lxml/lxml-stubs.git
```

(the project's readme installation command is missing the `git+` prefix in URL's scheme and won't work).

Comment: Seems to be buggy :(

```
error: Unexpected keyword argument "namespaces" for "find" of "_Element"; did you mean "namespace"?
error: "_Element" has no attribute "replace"
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to [check out types-lxml](https://pypi.org/project/types-lxml/) if any late comer are still interested. I have done quite some gap filling over the years, so now it can be considered completed for all major submodules: `lxml.etree`, `lxml.html` and `lxml.objectify`. The next release after March 2023 should cover everything except `lxml.isoschematron`, which does very powerful schema validation, but few people would use it.

> I’ve used `stubgen` to create stub type definitions and filling in “any”-types

This is actually the correct approach if it's not lxml; creating template from `mypy` `stubgen` is the starting point for many stub files. But lxml is mostly written in [Cython](https://cython.org/), for which stubgen do not have perfect support yet. Besides, as OP noted, this is a python 2.0 era module, and author uses function arguments in a quite polymorphous way. There are lots of unique challenges annotating lxml, as lxml is essentially a python interface for `libxml` and `libxslt` in its core.

As an example, the support of both `unicode` and `bytes` input complicates matter too; this is the same difficulty found when annotating `xml.etree` bundled with python, but in a much greater magnitude.

[Disclaimer: I'm maintainer of `types-lxml` package mentioned above]

Answer (score 1):

I would not call this "hacky", rather it is [gradual typing](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/#id8).

You can take a closer look at [lxml-stubs repository](https://github.com/lxml/lxml-stubs). From about:

> This repository contains external type annotations (see PEP 484) for the lxml package. Such type annotations are normally included in typeshed, but lxml's annotations were frequently problematic and have therefore been deleted from typeshed. In particular, the stubs are incomplete and it has been difficult to provide complete stubs.

Perhaps it will be useful to you