# Python type hints with lxml

Tags: python, lxml, type-hinting

I am trying out type hints. I glanced at every documentation I could find (mypy, source code of lxml-stubs etc., various tutorials), but obviously I am missing (overlooking) something.

How should I go about type hints with lxml?

I found [Type hints for lxml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63259362/) and I installed lxml-stub, but how should my code look like? Any (working) example greatly appreciated!